# Show array items in Swift (Pixabay api)

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I can't get results from the Pixabay API. I have tried everything but cannot see the error where the print returns zero.

This is my Swift code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct dataImg : Codable{
    let total: Int
    let hits : [hitsImages]


struct hitsImages: Codable {
    let fullHDURL : String
    let downloads : Int
}
    }
/*
struct PixaImage : Decodable {
    let total : Int
    let totalHits: Int
    let hits : [hitsImages]
}*/

let apiKey = "****" 
/*I've got the api in my swift but i don't wanna make it public :P*/
let urlParam = "&image_type=photo&orientation=vertical&lang=es"
let url = URL(string: "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=\(apiKey)")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, _, _) in
    if let data = data {
        let imagesdecoder = try? JSONDecoder().decode(dataImg.self, from: data)
        //Declaramos la url de la api y ejecutamos para ver que conecta -> corecta correctamente
        print(imagesdecoder?.total)
    }
}.resume()
```

The result of `print(imagesdecoder?.total)` is nil, but data gives me something like 15000 bytes of info. 
[Here, you can see the example of Pixabay's api](https://pixabay.com/api/docs/)

Comment: To me it looks like your url contains only your api key and no endpoint (query). Is `urlParam` your api query perhaps?

Comment: Before you try decode JSON, print "data.debugDescription" to see if returns the JSON correctly.

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde, this is the result: 16000 bytes, I think it is returning the size of the Json, not the information

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, only with the url + api key it works, the parameter I have put there hoping to have everything working to collect only vertical and landscape photos, but isn't necessary

Comment: Then add some proper error handling, change `try?` to `try` and surround the call with a `do{}catch{}` and use `print(error)` in the catch part. Maybe you also could check what you get back by executing the query in a browser.